# Make anchor text copyable

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a question regarding links and divs. I want the whole div to be clickable and in the same time the text should be copyable, so that the google bots for example can read them as text.

Anybody got any ideas?

my code looks like this :

```
<div id="menubutton1"><br>
  SOTNING</div>


#menubutton1{ width:149px; height:77px; float:left;margin-left:290px; text-align:center;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
   -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;

}


#menubutton1:hover{  
background-color: #F93;
 cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: probably better starting off with an <a></a> element, making it display:block; http://jsfiddle.net/Z9RZq/

Comment: what you mean by clickable? Listen click events?

Comment: Any reason why it has to be a `<div>` and not an `<a>` link?

Comment: Hey , not really a reason. When I say clickable I mean that for now the box change color in a transition. and thats all well and dandy,  and the curser changes to a hand on the entire box , BUT when i click nothing happens for the user, only when the text is clicked the page changes. and there for a problem . How would u go around with a <a> <a/>  ? becouse I have other links with just <a> that i dont want to be boxes. with regards / Johan

Comment: oh , misted that one Matt.C thats really Exacly what i want !! :) thank you kind sir

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create an anchor element, set that to `display:block` and `position:absolute`.  See below:

```
<div id="menubutton1">
    <a href="#" class="fill"></a>
    <p>You text which you want read by search engine bots.</p>
</div>
```

Add the following style

```
<style>
    #menubutton1{
        position:relative;
    }
    .fill{
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h5gq/1/).

The text won't be selectable directly from the DIV as the anchor block is floating over the top, but if selecting the page or from outside the DIV then the text can still be selected.

***There's no evidence showing this will affect search bots reading the content as the content is still visible.***

Alternatively you will need to use a JavaScript function to run on the click event and go to a specified link.  This will however cause a problem for a search bot as they don't knowingly read/follow JavaScript.  If you do choose the JS route I'd suggest having the link available on the page elsewhere too to ensure it is followed.

Comment: You won't be able to select the text, also you are missing one semi colon http://jsfiddle.net/SuTr7/

Comment: perfect ,did this and its now working !! thx    #menubutton1{
        position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-left:290px; height:77px; width:149px;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
    }
    .fill{
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0
    }
 
 #menubutton1:hover{  
background-color: #F93;
  cursor: pointer;}

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark the answer as completed for future users with the same question.

Comment: Next to each answer there are ranking arrows with a number in the middle.  Below this you will see an outline of a tick.  Click the tick of the correct answer and the question will be marked as solved.  For more info on accepting answers see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).